# How to share files between projects?

Tags: godot, godot-4

Ok so, I want to have a discreet client and server project.

This project necessarily must have some of the same files so the server can do calculations/collisions/etc. Instead of having to copy files from one project to the other, is there a way to share the files between the projects and avoid having to deal with revision control between the projects?

I have already tried creating a Shared folder with symlinks to the source folder, but this produces errors at runtime and corrupts files.

Does anyone know of a way to share these files

Comment: Have you tried using something like git submodules? Also it's worth mentioning that this is usually handled in a single project using separate export presets for client and server.

Comment: There are use cases for using export presets like you have mentioned, it's not going to work here. Using submodules doesn't solve the underlying problem of Godot thumb-printing files with a project thumbprint, and I don't mean the imports folder. res and tscn files get a thumbprint inside the file itself. It ends up being the same problem as a symlinked folder, it just delays exposing the problem till a little later.